# How to make react-confetti start from current div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas

I've a next application with mui.

My application is a form like Typeform, you answer a question and go to next one, each question takes the whole viewport, in the last question I want to render react-confetti.

Question1:

[image]

Question2:

[image]

The issue: it shows confetis but in the beggining of the page instead of current question.

Confetti in first question not the last:

[image]

```bash
yarn add @mui react-use react-confetti
```

This is my index.tsx:

```js
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { useState } from 'react'
import useWindowSize from 'react-use/lib/useWindowSize'
const Confetti = dynamic(() => import('react-confetti'), {
  ssr: false,
})

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowSize()
  const [run, setRun] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        id="welcome"
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '100vh', textAlign: 'center' }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
            Hello User!
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom>
            Tell more about your experience with us
          </Typography>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ marginBottom: '1em' }} size="large">
            Start
          </Button>
          <Typography variant="caption" display="block" gutterBottom>
            It takes less than 1 minute
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      {run && (
        <Confetti
          height={height}
          width={width}
          recycle={false}
          numberOfPieces={1000}
          onConfettiComplete={() => setRun(false)}
        />
      )}
      <Grid
        id="suggestion"
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '100vh', textAlign: 'center' }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            Any suggestions to improve our space?
          </Typography>
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            size="medium"
            label="Leave your suggestion"
            fullWidth
            color="primary"
            margin="dense"
          />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            sx={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
            size="large"
            disabled={run}
            onClick={() => setRun(true)}
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @kd12345 I post an answer with the whole component, I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I ended it up moving the component to its own page:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { FC } from 'react'
import useWindowSize from 'react-use/lib/useWindowSize'
const Confetti = dynamic(() => import('react-confetti'), {
  ssr: false,
})

const FinishPage: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { customerName } = router.query
  const { width, height } = useWindowSize()
  const title = `Muito obrigado ${customerName} ❤️`

  return (
    <div>
      {customerName && (
        <Head>
          <title>{title}</title>
        </Head>
      )}
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '100vh', textAlign: 'center' }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={3} style={{ marginRight: '10px', marginLeft: '10px' }}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            Muito obrigado{' '}
            {customerName && (
              <>
                <br />
                <span className="highlight">{customerName}</span>
                <br />
              </>
            )}
            por sua contribuição ❤️
          </Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Confetti height={height} width={width} recycle={false} numberOfPieces={2000} />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FinishPage
```